# A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I try to run my application, I ge the the following error;
[image]

I know this issue has come up many times, and the usual answer is to right click on the appropriate project and make it the start up project.

Well I have done that and this does not fix it.

My application is an MVC application, so the start up project should be a class library.

It was working fine until I tried to upgrade it to MVC5.

I am working on VS 2012.

I am wondering if the problem was caused by unloading and reloading the csproj file which I edited as part of the upgrade?

Comment: re _"My application is an MVC application, so the start up project should be a class library."_. The startup application is the MVC project if you want to "run" the `application`. A class `library` is not "run" (as the name implies). Your MVC application _depends_ (has a dependency) on it - perhaps that's what you mean...Hth.

Answer (score 41):

I think it might have something to do if there are multiple projects in the solution. I was getting the same problem when I had a MVC project and the testing project in the same solution. What fixed it for me was setting the MVC project as the StartUp project. This is done by right clicking on the MVC project and selecting "Set as StartUp Project".

This works for VS2013 Professional

Comment: This just solved my issue in VS2017 Enterprise when opening an existing project up for the first time on a new PC.

Comment: This also solves my issue in VS2015 Professional. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and corrected by altering the projecttype guid. Here is an example:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: I had an empty <ProjectTypeGuids></ProjectTypeGuids> below the ones you stated. After removing those it was fixed.