# A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly --> vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I did much R & D on the above issue, and I got to know is, change the current project to "Set as StartUp Project" by right clicking on the solution. As the same I followed, could not make my solution to run properly. Can anybody help me please.

Here is the error dialog box appearing to me when I click to run the code.

[image]

Comment: A class library can only be used by *another* project that loads it.  It is completely unclear from the question what that project should look like but an obvious way to go about it is to add a little test console mode project to the solution that exercises your library.  Make that project your startup project.  If there is any relevance at all to the [vb6] tag you used then you must explain that in your question.

Comment: Just to add to what's been said, you don't *have* to create a console app and add it to your solution. You can attach a class library to a running process. This is actually how some applications need to be started, in order to properly debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456571/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)